# How can one solve $yy''+\frac12(b-1)(y')^2 -\frac12(b+1)y^2-bcy =A$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can one solve the second order nonlinear differential equation $yy''+\frac12(b-1)(y')^2 -\frac12(b+1)y^2-bcy =A$? Here, $A,b,c$ are constants and $y(t)$ is a function.

Comment: I added mathjax to the post, and removed the second paragraph which I thought was unclear. If you think the second paragraph was important, please do put it back with an edit, making it clearer what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's autonomous, you can write this as a first order equation for $y'$ in terms of $y$.  You then get solutions

$$ \int ^{y \left( x \right) }\!{\frac {\sqrt {b-1}}{\sqrt {2\,c
 \left( b-1 \right) {s}+ \left( b-1 \right) {s}^{2}+C
 \left( b-1 \right) {s}^{1-b}+2\,A}}}{ds}=B\pm x
$$
where $B$ and $C$ are arbitrary constants.

I would expect that for most values of $b$ this can not be done in "closed form".

Comment: thanks @Robert Israel

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Robert Israel
But I want to write the equation as follows
(yy')^2 = F(y); F(y) = {y^4} + 2c{y^3} + A{y^2} + B{y^{3 - b}}
How can I do this by once integrating this equation
yy''+\frac12(b-1)(y')^2 -\frac12(b+1)y^2-bcy =A

Comment: @Robert Israel Can you provide me some more info about how you arrived at this integral?

Comment: @cgiovanardi you can arrived  this integral by using Maple 
[> y(x)*(diff(y(x), x, x, x))+b*(diff(y(x), x))*(diff(y(x), x, x))-(b+1)*y(x)*(diff(y(x), x))-b*c*(diff(y(x), x)) = 0;

[> dsolve(y(x)*(diff(y(x), x, x, x))+b*(diff(y(x), x))*(diff(y(x), x, x))-(b+1)*y(x)*(diff(y(x), x))-b*c*(diff(y(x), x)) = 0, {y(x)});

[>